# REACT-PDF utils.js:187 Error: Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url

Tags: reactjs, pdf

**    Problema que salta  al intentar añadir un pdf con formato utf 8, mi intencion es mostrar este pdf con chrome utilizo react-pdf
**

```
            <Document
          file={pdf}
          onLoadSuccess={()=> alert('PDF CARGADO')}
        >
          <Page pageNumber={1} />
        </Document>
```

Comment: No he usado nunca la librería para saber exactamente su funcionamiento, sin embargo sería bueno que especificaras la librería y la versión, ya que estuve viendo la documentación de un [react-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/components#document) y al parecer no recibe como props ni `file` ni `onLoadSuccess`. Por otro lado, sería bueno saber qué es tu objeto `pdf`

Comment: La ultima versión aqui tienes un enlace para saber más sobre esta versión... https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf mi pdf es un archivo que he recibido d euna consulta a la API y he tenido que codificarla a unicode

Comment: Si lees la documentación del paquete que me acabas de enviar, dice que la propiedad `file` recibe o un `string` como url, o un objeto file que importes directamente o un objeto que crees para que la librería sea quien hace la consulta. En vez de generar el archivo y hacer la llamada a la api tu deberías pasarle algo así a tu `Document`: `file={{ url: url_de_tu_api }}` o si de alguna forma puedes sacar la data de tu `pdf` sería algo como: `file={{ data: pdf.data }}`